# Dynamic Webhook URL assign on twilio while purchasing twilio number or after that

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

Can i dynamically assign voice URL(webhook URL) on twilio while i am purchasing a number from my sub account using API? 
At this moment if i manually assign the voice URL i am receiving incoming call successfully. Is there any other way to solve the issue.

Comment: solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, look at the IncomingPhoneNumber resource, more specifically at [Create an IncomingPhoneNumber resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource#create-an-incomingphonenumber-resource) and the associated parameters you can pass in.